# execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, trigger, controller

Here is my very super simple code and what I'm trying to do is returning the Id... that's all I'm doing.

Getting the following error:

> Apex trigger test caused an unexpected exception, contact your
>   administrator: test: execution of AfterUpdate caused by:
>   System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Apex code:

```
public class scheduleController 
{
    public  scheduleController() 
    {

    }  

    public static string ShowDebugMessage(){

       String currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
       system.debug('currentRecordId  :  ' + currentRecordId)  ;

     if(String.isBlank(currentRecordId))
     {
         return 'its empty' ;    
     }
     else
     {
         return 'its not empty';
     }

     return 'return nothing!!!';
    }
}
```

Trigger that's firing the apex code:

```
trigger MyFirstTrigger on customSchedule__c (after insert, after update) 
{
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){

      system.debug('ShowDebugMessage  ' + scheduleController.ShowDebugMessage());
    }
}
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it being called from a VF Page? If yes, you should deal with page parameters in Controller only not in Trigger's handler code.

Comment: its calling from trigger not VF page

Comment: It doesn't make sense of using Page parameters in Trigger handler's code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through how triggers work in Salesforce and how you can retrieve context variables in there.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm

The problem in above code is in this line
String currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');

This code is applicable to VisualForce page controllers only, as only they would have "CurrentPage" initiatlized, in case of trigger execution it would give null, hence you get the error.